# How can we relate the two informal definitions of the limit with each other?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

**Informal definition $1$**:

*This is the way in which I studied it, and it makes sense to me*.

As $x$ gets closer and closer to $a$, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $l$.

---

**Informal definition $2$**:

$f(x)$ can get arbitrarily close to $l$, by taking $x$ sufficiently close to $a$.

---

I am not able to relate these two informal definitions. How do we relate these definitions?

Comment: By seeing how they both originate from the formal definition, perhaps?

Comment: @Arthur I was thinking about understanding the formal definition by using these informal definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second informal definition is more precise. Here's the problem with the first one: consider $f(x) = x^2$, and take $x \rightarrow 0$. Now I claim that the limit is $-1$:

> As $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $-1$.

This statement is true, but the actual limit is certainly not $-1$.

The problem with the first definition is that it's so informal that it's missing the critical part of the concept, which is that I should be able to make it *as close as I want to $-1$* by choosing values of $x$ close to $0$ (which I can't in this case). That precision is what the second definition supplies.

Comment: From a [near-number](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412157) standpoint, "closer and closer to zero" can be interpreted as the mathematical object $0^+$. Here, $0^+$ means squeezing closer and closer to zero forever.

Comment: I am not sure why you said "Now I claim that the limit is $−1$". How can you do that when the limit is $0$?

Comment: @NSR Indeed, my point was to show that the first definition is problematic. My claim is (wrongly) supported by the first definition, which I cited in the line following the claim. In general, that definition would support the claim that the limit is $L$ for any $L\le0$, which is absurd.

Comment: @NirajRaut That looks like a very interesting paper. Really, this whole question comes down to what we mean by "closer and closer". I've intentionally interpreted the phrase rather loosely to show why it could be misleading, but if you describe it more carefully or formally, then it would be fine. But as soon as you describe it more formally, you no longer have an informal definition...

Comment: *"As $x$ gets closer and closer to $0$, $f(x)$ gets closer and closer to $-1$.

This statement is true, but the actual limit is certainly not $-1$."* — How is this statement true? Please clarify. I mean it should be "closer and closer to $0$". How did you (wrongly) claim it?

Comment: @NSR Let's calculate some values of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $0$: $f(10)=100, f(3)=9, f(2)=4, f(1)=1, f(0.5)=0.25$. Do you agree that the numbers $100,9,4,1,0.25$ are getting progressively closer to $-1$? To put it another way: given two numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$, if $x_1$ is closer than $x_2$ to $0$, then $f(x_1)$ will be closer than $f(x_2)$ to $-1$.

Comment: On the same point, Can I say that it approaches $1$? I mean it can approach any value, right?

Comment: No, it cannot approach any value; as $x \rightarrow 0$, the values of $f(x)$ are getting farther and farther from $1$ (or any other positive number), not closer.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please  explain.

Comment: Can they get closer to $-2$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112576/discussion-between-theophile-and-nsr).

Answer (score 2):

The first informal definition suggests motion: as $x$ somehow "approaches" or "gets closer to" $a$, the value $f(x)$ approaches $L$.

The second informal definition is actually the formal definition, written in English. Mathematicians designed it to capture the idea of "approaches" without the need for vague terms like "closer and closer to".

The English phrase "arbitrarily close to $L$" is written more formally as "closer than $\epsilon$ for any particular $\epsilon$ you may have in mind." The "arbitrary" says "for any possible $\epsilon$."

The "sufficiently close to $a$" is written more formally as "you can find a $\delta$ (which will usually depend on $\epsilon$) that will guarantee $f(x)$ within $\epsilon$ of $L$ as long as $x$ is within $\delta$ of $a$." The $\delta$ is sufficient (i.e. good enough) to guarantee the $\epsilon$ closeness of $f(x)$ to $L$.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentence render the part

$$|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$$ of the formal definition.

But the definition 1 is lacking an essential ingredient: $\epsilon$ can be *as small as we want*. Indeed, we could have smaller and smaller $\delta$ corresponding to smaller and smaller *but bounded below* $\epsilon$.